# iPhone keyboard return key color

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

Can we change the color of the iPhone keyboard return key color?? And does apple supports it?? If yes could you please help me out in changing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API available for it.

If you do with private API then your app will be get rejected in app store.

Comment: Thank you saurabh.We are developing an for the app store only.