# How to change color of return key of keyboard in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone keyboard return key color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659421/iphone-keyboard-return-key-color)

How to change color of return key of keyboard in iPhone?

Comment: if we are talking about the standard keyboard i don't think you can't, at least not using the public API's. You could create your own keypad and change the colore there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually no official way to change the color. All you could do is write your own keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way to change the return key color. But you can have different options for return key, as `UITextField` has a property `returnKeyType`.

```
yourTextField.returnKeyType  = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

And these are the  other allowable types

```
typedef enum {
   UIReturnKeyDefault,
   UIReturnKeyGo,
   UIReturnKeyGoogle,
   UIReturnKeyJoin,
   UIReturnKeyNext,
   UIReturnKeyRoute,
   UIReturnKeySearch,
   UIReturnKeySend,
   UIReturnKeyYahoo,
   UIReturnKeyDone,
   UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
} UIReturnKeyType;
```

You can read Apple's documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html). [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872218/i-want-change-the-return-key-of-iphone-virtual-key-to-a-another-name) also explains this.

Comment: next time just flag the question as duplicate to earn your badge.

Comment: oops sorry..but how can I flag?

Comment: k understood, still learning about SO rules...sorry

Comment: No problem.  I am still learning also.  Under each question you should see lin | edit | flag.  Also a comment field which I also let the poster know his question is possible a duplicate.